# How can I remove Colorings of files in the Explorer view indicating file changes?

Tags: javascript, angular, visual-studio-code

I am doing an Angular project in vscode and I have installed VScode in my PC and i'm using vscode in my laptop before installing it in PC. so my question is in Explorer in vscode the files are in green color, and I find the coloring annoying.

I have tried changing the color theme but to no avail. How can this be changed?

[image: explorer in Vscode]

Comment: Have you tried following the instructions from the [official website](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes)?

Comment: I tried to write an improved answer that shows how to turn that setting off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are green because you have a git repository in this folder and the files are untracked (hence U symbol)

Either track them or remove the git repository

Comment: Note: green isn't the only decoration colouring there is. once tracked, modified files will be coloured yellow. this doesn't really address the persistent issue, and the asker indicated that they "_find the coloring annoying._"

Answer (score 1):

These colours in the explorer view are called "git decorations". They are enabled by default in workspaces that have an associated git repository, and the colours indicate what has changed about the file.

- red (with the "D" letter) means things have been deleted
- yellow (with the "M" letter) indicates things have been modified
- green (with the letter "A" or "U") means things have been added (AKA "staged") or are not yet added ("untracked").

> and I find the coloring annoying.

If you want to turn git decorations off, you can do so by putting the following in your user settings.json, or in your workspace's `.vscode/settings.json` file:

```json
"git.decorations.enabled": false
```